# How to use python remote interpreter in CLion

Tags: python, clion

I want to use remote Python Interpreter in CLion, and I do not find corresponding config in Clion.

I have try to config in Preferences >> Build, Execution, Deployment >> Python Interpreter.

But I don't find where to config a remote Python Interpreter in CLion.[Here is the config page for Python Interpreter but not where for remote interpreter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c03ls.png)

Answer (score 0):

CLion has Community Python plugin inside. That means [it does not support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-13470) remote Python Interpreter.